# EmberJS nested dynamic routes don't redirect as expected

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Using Ember 2.17.0, I can't seem to get routes nested under other dynamic routes to load properly.

With the following file structure I'd like the `stacks` route to load a new page.

```
features/instances/
├── edit
│   ├── route.js
│   └── template.hbs
├── index
│   ├── route.js
│   └── template.hbs
├── new
│   ├── route.js
│   └── template.hbs
└── view
    ├── route.js
    ├── stacks
    │   ├── route.js
    │   └── template.hbs
    └── template.hbs
```

The URL for the `stacks` endpoint looks like `/instances/view/91467053-ba03-33b9-8950-83f0e64b4688/stacks/123456`

Where `123456` is the ID of the stack model. However at the moment when I trigger the link above the page doesn't reload and I'm still on the `view` route. If I put a `{{outlet}}` tag into the `view` template, the content of the `stacks` is rendered there. But I want it on it's own page...

My router.js

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('instances', function () {

    this.route('view', {path: '/view/:instance_id'}, function () {
      this.route('stacks', {path: '/stacks/:stack_id'});
    });

    this.route('edit');
    this.route('new');
    this.route('all');

  });
  this.route('error');
});
```

What have I done wrong here? I can't find much about nested dynamic routes for ember 2.0+

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm understanding your problem correctly. There are two ways to do this:

1) instead of `view/template.hbs` put that HTML in `view/index/template.hbs`, that way `view/stacks/template.hbs` will share none of the `view` template code.

2) instead of nesting the `stacks` route in the `view` route you pull up to the `instances` route with `path: '/view/:instance_id/stacks/:stack_id'`, and then move the route/template files accordingly

Comment: Thanks for the response, RE option 1, if I do what you've suggested, things get weird, as their is the index folder above the view route already. so requests to my backend become `/instances/e3f61b5a-89e3-3d1c-a3ce-e0df22817a9b` rather than `/instances/view/e3f61b5a-89e3-3d1c-a3ce-e0df22817a9b`

Comment: And following option 2, I get no console errors, but the page is just blank. Like the template.hbs is being completely ignored.

Comment: The backend request URLs should be unrelated to your frontend route structure. You might have to explicitly implement all the model hooks though.

Answer (score 0):

Nested routes in Ember don't work as you're used to.

Where in most other view frameworks, a nested route implies a relation between objects, in Ember nested routes imply a nested view.

So for example you could have a messages.index route which nests a messages.show route if you would like to have a list of messages rendered and the ability to open them in a detail pane next to it.

If you want to render something independent (so not nested in another view) simply give it its own route.